# FXML document naming convention

Tags: javafx, naming-conventions, fxml

Is there a specific document **naming convention** I should follow when creating **FXML** files or XML files in general? I've been following some tutorials that Oracle has provided and come to the conclusion that FXML files should start with the **prefix**

```
fxml
```

and end with the **suffix**

```
view
```

So an example FXML document would look like

```
fxml_tableview.fxml
```

Tutorial source: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/jfxpub-fxml_get_started.htm
Specific page: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/fxml_tutorial_intermediate.htm

Comment: Which tutorials are you referring to? e(fx)clipse demands that FXML filenames begin with a capital letter (like class names). [afterburner.fx](https://github.com/AdamBien/afterburner.fx/) is a framework using a convention-over-configuration approach that relies on filenames like `example.fxml`, `ExampleView.java`, `ExamplePresenter.java` and, optionally, `example.css`. I don't think there's any particularly standardized approach for general JavaFX applications.

Comment: Thanks for linking the tutorials. I had seen those tutorials, but hadn't paid particular attention to the filenames. I don't think that style is widely used; the `fxml_` prefix seems particularly redundant.

Comment: As the author of e(fx)clipse to me following the Java classnameing convention felt natural but i don't think there is a common rule

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CERN paper on JavaFX includes a section on naming conventions.

> Both, the FXML file and its controller should have names allowing an
> easy identification that they belong to the same view, without looking
> at their content. In fact, JavaFX introduced a naming convention for
> nested controllers. For instance, if an included view ID is `dialog`,
> then the corresponding controller can be referenced as
> `dialogController`. This convention could be extended to other
> entities associated with a single view such as model, service, CSS or
> resource bundle properties file. In addition, all files related to a
> single view could be placed in a dedicated Java package, named after
> the view. In such case the content of every package would be similar:
>
> • [view_name].fxml
>
> • [view_name]Controller.java
>
> • [view_name]Model.java
>
> • [view_name]Service.java
>
> • [view_name].css
>
> • [view_name].properties
>
> Note that only the FXML, controller and in most cases also model files
> are be present, while CSS, resource bundle and any additional files
> are optional. Such convention is very easy to remember. With a glimpse
> of an eye one can recognize all the elements and have a good idea what
> is inside.

Source: [Best Practices For Efficient Development Of JavaFX Applications](https://accelconf.web.cern.ch/icalepcs2017/papers/thapl02.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

I just blogged about the naming conventions I can recommend:

> If "mypackage.**<name>**.java" loads a FXML file, then the FXML file
>   should be **in the same package** and be named "**<name>.fxml**".

One advantage is, that when following this naming convention it's quite easy to see, which FXML loader/ fx:root-controller and FXML file belong together.

Another advantage is, that the loading code can be simplified.

You can read more about it here: http://puces-blog.blogspot.ch/2015/03/drombler-commons-conventions-to.html